# How can I cast/convert an int to an object? (java)

Tags: java, object, casting, int

It's just that. I would like to know how to cast/convert an int to an object, I've been trying few days but still stuck there.

If you could give me a small example with just one integer.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: You were trying to convert an int to an object in Java for a few days? Out of curiosity do you know Google?

Answer (score 4):

You can cast an `int` as an instance of its wrapper class (`Integer`), and then assign that to an `Object` if you like.

For example:

```
int i = 1;
Integer myInt = Integer.valueOf(i);
Object myObject = myInt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `Object` is the base class for all the objects, you can use directly `Object` object to modify value of the Integer object.

```
Integer integer = 10;
Object object = integer + 20;
```